# s6-overlay starting process even if service name is missing from user/contents.d bundle

Tags: docker, s6

I've read through all the docs for S6-overlay (https://github.com/just-containers/s6-overlay) but I must have missed a nuance somewhere.

From what I understand, only the service names that are defined in the `/etc/s6-overlay/s6-rc.d/user/contents.d/` folder should be launched at the start of the container.

For debugging purposes, I have removed some service names from the `user/contents.d/` folder, and yet still see the `oneshoot` type service starting up.

Is the user/contents.d folder only for supervised `longrun` services?  I would have expected that the `oneshot` type services also not launch.